# File upload in Resteasy

Tags: java, file, rest, upload, resteasy

How to upload files using RESTEasy framework ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is [an example](http://ankiewsky.blogspot.com/2008/07/resteasy-tips-part-1.html) which uses commons-fileupload along with RESTEasy

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good example:

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/